# Upgrade SBS 2008 to SBS 2011

Tags: windows-sbs-2008, windows-sbs-2011

I am migrating from SBS 2008 to SBS 2011 but the Microsoft documentation does not yet exist. 
Has anyone done this yet?
What are the recommended steps/procedures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft has now posted the documentation on how to do this
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615506.aspx

Answer (score 0):

SBS 2011 just released to manufacturing last month (it's not even on my Partner access yet) so it looks like there isn't a lot of third party posts about migrations. From the few that I have it looks to be similar to the migration from SBS 2003 to SBS 2008.

I think the only exception would be the migration from SBS 2008 to SBS 2011 Essentials which is a cloud based offering.

http://www.sbsfaq.com/?p=2351
http://blog.mpecsinc.ca/2010/12/sbs-2003-to-sbs-2011-microsoft.html
http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2010/12/13/windows-small-business-server-2011-standard-releases-to-manufacturing.aspx

SBS 2003 to SBS 2008 Guides:
http://blog.mpecsinc.ca/2009/06/sbs-2003-to-sbs-2008-migration-guide.html
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbs-2008-2003-migration(WS.10).aspx

Comment: I have it available in my technet subscription so I attempted to do a migration the same way I did from SBS 2003 to SBS 2008 but i ran into some errors so I am not sure if there is new steps I don't know about.

Answer (score -1):

I did this a while back using the Microsoft method, there is details inside the SBS 2011 Administrators Companion that outline how to do it.

I must say, having followed it step by step, I did run in to a number of catastrophic errors so I would recommend building a test environment imaging your existing SBS 2008 server, restoring it to your test lab and trying it for real.